# Can't add any function to my javascript sheet

Tags: javascript

this is my first time here and I'm still learning javascript so it may have a lot of "newb" mistakes.

I, normally, like to solves problems by myself but I'm facing something weird. I'm working on a website for school and made few simple functions to display a div and hide another.

Here's the JS sheet :

```
function openSel(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
  }

  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
}

// MODAL PANIER
function showCart() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeCart() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

// SECTION AMD
function showAmd() {
  document.getElementById("amd").style.display = "block";
}

function hideChoice() {
  document.getElementById("config-choice").style.display = "none";
}

function openAmd() {
  showAmd();
  hideChoice();
}

function hideAmd() {
  document.getElementById("amd").style.display = "none";
}

function showConfig() {
  document.getElementById("config-choice").style.display = "block";
}

function showChoice() {
  hideAmd();
  showConfig();
}
```

The two problems are :

1- I can't add any function.

2- On my HTML, if I call an `onclick` function on a button, none of my functions work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What do you mean you "can't add any function"? Have you opened your console (hit F12) and checked for errors?

Comment: `onclick` and similar attributes can only reach functions defined in the global scope. First, check for other errors; if a script includes a syntax error, the entire script can be invalid. Also, make sure no other `function`s are surrounding these – event handlers, etc.

Comment: The console doesn't give me any error.

And the "I can't add any function" : 

function showChoice() {
  hideAmd();
  showConfig();
}

is the limit. I cannot add any other function to this sheet.